# Overlaying and repeating image with blank image in imagemagick's new version

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to overlay 100X100 image on blank 1080X1320 image by repetition.

```
    $ThumbImg = 'thumb_100x100.png';
    $new_image = "new.png";

    exec("convert -size 1080x1320! xc:transparent all_images/" . $new_image);

   $new_image_path = 'all_images/' . $new_image;

     // main image  width=1080 ,height = 1320,
     // thumb image width = 100 , height = 100,
     // row=1320/100=14
     // col=1080/100=11

    for ($row = 0; $row < 14; $row++)
    {
       for ($col = 0; $col < 11; $col++)
       {
         exec('composite -geometry +' . ($col * 100) . '+' . ($row * 100) . ' ' . $ThumbImg . ' ' . $new_image_path . ' ' . $new_image_path);

       }
    }
```

When i use above code on version 6.9 it works fine and 100x100 image gets repeated uniformly over blank 1080x1320 image. But this doesn't work on 7.0.3 version (latest IM version).

what change would be needed in `exec` command to make this work on newer version?

**UPDATE -**

Solution suggested by `mark-setchell` is working for some patterns but for following it doesn't create an image but instead only blank image is created.

[image: Lining pattern image]

**UPDATE -**

We need to use `-set colorspace RGB` in command to get the right result. So command would be

```
exec('convert new.png -fill thumb.png -set colorspace RGB -draw "color 0,0 reset" result.png');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be simpler to just use **ImageMagick**'s `-fill` operator to tile your 100x100 image over a background.

So, if we create a 100x100 tile to repeat like this:

```
convert -size 100x100 gradient:cyan-magenta tile.png
```

[image]

Then you can tile that all over a 1080x1320 background like this:

```
convert xc:black"[1080x1320]"  -fill tile.png -draw "color 0,0 reset" result.png
```

[image]

If you want to generate the tile pattern *"on-the-fly"* in one command, you can do it like this using an MPR (Magick Pixel Register) in memory to hold the fill:

```
convert -size 100x100 gradient:cyan-magenta -write MPR:tile +delete \
   xc:black"[1080x1320]" -fill MPR:tile -draw "color 0,0 reset" result.png
```

If you wish to continue to use the original `composite` command, you need to re-order the parameters as follows with IM v7:

```
composite new.png -geometry +400+900 tile.png result.png
```

Comment: I didn't get why you used gradient here, I have not worked on IM before so, if you can edit the single command using `thumb.png` and `new.png` it would be better. `thumb.png` is 100x100 pattern image i am using and `new.png` is 1080x1320 image i am creating from pattern image.

Comment: I only used a gradient so you can see that it really is tiled :-) If you use a solid colour, the tiled image just comes out solid so you can't tell that it is a repeated pattern.

Comment: Your command would be `convert new.png -fill thumb.png -draw "color 0,0 reset" result.png`

Comment: Thanks, it works. I would check it for different patterns.

Comment: hey `mark-setchell` i have updated answer and for some pattern images this command doesn't work, i dont know what causes this.

Comment: Your sample tile works ok for me - what doesn't work for you? Maybe try setting `-channel RGBA` before the `-draw` or maybe `-channel RGB`.

Comment: Ok, i have used ` -set colorspace RGB` and its working fine now, but what if i want to place blocks of 100x100 on large image from left-top to right-bottom just as i coded for 6.9 IM version? is it possible in 7.0.3?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. The order of the parameters has been rationalised to be more sensible, so you should load the background image, then set the geometry and then load the thumb on top now... `composite new.png -geometry +400+900 tile.png  result.png`